# angular 2 make mdl-badge data-badge content dynamic

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, badge

i'm using angular 2 material design and i want bind data to the mdl-badge but I get an error when i doing this way.

**html code**

```
 <div class="material-icons mdl-badge mdl-badge--overlap" data-badge={{numFlags}}>num Of flags</div>
```

**ts component**

```
   this.numFlags=msg++;
```

Comment: What error? Maybe it's worth nothing, but have you tried: `[data-badge]=numFlags`?

Comment: yes i tried it write me into the data-badge "numflags" . i want the value of the numflags. to bind the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That syntax is not valid. You have to use

`[attr.data-badge]="numFlags"`

or

`attr.data-badge={{numFlags}}`

in order to bind `numFlags` to `data-badge`.

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yokFrRV4j4BJKVly92rp?p=preview)